# Como faço para receber um valor booleano "new" de uma estrutura json em Java?

Tags: java, json, api, sintaxe, conversão-de-tipo

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome uma API, até então está tudo ok. Porém no corpo do Json vem um valor booleano "new" e por ser uma palavra reservada em Java não consigo recuperar o valor recebido. Segue o exemplo.

```
    {
      "id": 7502,
      "description": "Frete grátis em todo site",
      "vigency": "31/12/2022 23:59:00",
      "new": false
    }
```

A classe que recebe os valores

```
public class Cupons {

private String id;
private String description;
private String vigency;
private boolean new; // aqui está o erro. Se eu coloco a palavra 'novo' o valor não é recebido
```

}

Teria alguma maneira de ao invés de usar a palavra "new", usar a palavra "novo" e receber os valores de forma correta? Talvez uma `@annotation`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque para C# ;)

Brincadeiras a parte, não tem jeito de usar palavra reservada como nome de identificador em Java, você tem que escolher um outro nome na fonte, já que deve usar algo que gere o dado na classe para você, ou deve olhar a documentação da tecnologia que usa para gerar a classe partindo do JSON e ver como é possível dar um nome diferente do que vem no JSON, possivelmente tem alguma anotação para fazer isto, ou algum método que permite renomear antes de gerar o dado. Por exemplo:

- [Com GSON](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).
- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations).
- [Manualmente](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-deserialize-json-properties-that-are-reserved-words-in-apex).

Se você não usa algo que faça a geração deve ver o que tem que mudar no seu código para isso, mas acho que não é o caso.

Comment: as anotações do Gson que estão na documentação ajudaram bastante. Usei a @SerializedName("new") na classe e consegui recuperar o valor true/false e atribui à uma variavél booleana. Ficou assim:

`public class Cupons {

private String id;
private String description;
private String vigency;
@SerializedName("new")
private boolean novo;
}`

Value pela força.